# Add an existing user and INSERT it into another table: don't know what is the syntax in PDO

Tags: php, html, pdo

This is my code and I am new in programming and this is for our capstone project.

I want to SELECT an existing user from 'employee' table and INSERT only the primary key of the user into 'departmenthead' table to set him/her as a Department Head.

My problem is I don't know what is the perfect syntax for it and I tried to run my code there is no error displayed just white page.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('include/db.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0){
    header('location:index.php');
}
else{
if(isset($_GET['empid'])){
    $id=$_GET['empid'];
    $query1=$dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO departmenthead SELECT * FROM employee WHERE emp_id=:empid');
    $query2=$dbh->prepare('UPDATE FROM employee WHERE emp_id=:empid');
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    if ($query1->execute([':empid' => $id]) && $query2->execute([':empid' => $id])) {
        $dbh->commit();
            header("Location:adddepthead.php");
        } else {
            $dbh->rollBack();
        }
}?>
```

Comment: White page usually means there was an error but you didn't have error reporting switched on in your PHP settings. Or you switched it off via the error_reporting command, as in this case

Comment: Also if your query fails your script doesn't output anything anyway, so that could be another reason

Comment: thank you sir, this is the error message Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\samp\admin\adddepthead.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\samp\admin\adddepthead.php(14): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\samp\admin\adddepthead.php on line 14

Comment: Well `SELECT * FROM employee` isn't going to work, because I expect the department head table doesn't have the  exact same fields as employee? Or at least it shouldn't. You need to specify which field(s) you want to insert, and which field(s) of departmenthead you want to insert them into

Comment: P.S. you don't need the UPDATE query (it's not necessary, the syntax is wrong and your code never executes it anyway)

Comment: Thank you very much sir for giving me an idea to fix my problem hope to hear from you again sir. I just change my query to be more specific of its field(s), $query=$dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO departmenthead(dept_id, Status) SELECT emp_id, Status FROM employee WHERE emp_id=:empid');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not specifying columns

```
"INSERT INTO departmenthead (id, name, surname) 
SELECT id, name, surname
    FROM employee WHERE emp_id=:empid "
```

NOTE: Columns return from select do matched with insert column

Your query is also correct but columns does't matched its better to specify columns

Remove query2 its not doing anything

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your answer it fixes my problem, hope to hear more about you sir!